# Found no receiver for incoming [xxxx] on playerPrefab

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I have a problem with Unity Unet. I am trying to spawn a player on the map. The player appears on the server and on the client, but I have the following error :

> Found no receiver for incoming [xxxxxx] on playerPrefab, the server and the client should have the same NetworkBehaviour instances.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

EDIT :

Here are pictures of NetworkManager settings and PlayerPrefab settings

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you spawn player(code)? Player prefab settings (screenshot)?

Comment: Did you by any chance derive from a class which inherits NetworkBehaviour? And which version of Unity are you on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the player prefab in the Network Manager since it is trying to auto create it and you didn't specify one.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmEyI.png)

Comment: Yes I know it. It is empty because I get it dynamically with the character the player has chosen

Comment: if you want the client to be able to select the prefab you must do it by network messages, take a look at this [link](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-set-individual-playerprefab-form-client-in-the-networkmanger.348337/#post-2256378)